# AWS Java SDK SQSlistener endpoint issues

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I am using the AWS Java SDK as well as the spring cloud aws to utilize SES and SQS in my project. I am running into a small issue. When I try running my app I get the error:

> Error creating bean with name 'simpleMessageListenerContainer' defined
>   in class path resource
>   [org/springframework/cloud/aws/messaging/config/annotation/SqsConfiguration.class]:
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   com.amazonaws.services.sqs.model.AmazonSQSException: Credential should
>   be scoped to a valid region, not 'queue'.

As a preface, in my `app.properties` file, I have a property `queue.endpoint=https://queue.amazonaws.com/1234567890/queue-name.fifo` and the endpoint is retrieved from the aws cli.

I've read the AWS documentation and found out that this endpoint is a legacy endpoint. This property is used by the `@SqsListener` annotation from spring cloud aws library.

I managed to avoid this issue by seeing if I was using a legacy endpoint and converted it into the non-legacy endpoint through a shell script, ie `https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/123456780/queue-name.fifo`.

I was wondering if the spring cloud aws library had issues with using legacy endpoints. I noticed there were no issues for my other queues where the endpoints were `https://us-east-2.queue.amazonaws.com/1234567890/queue2-name.fifo` however, so maybe it parsed the `us-east-1` legacy endpoint incorrectly? I am also unsure if there were any configurations that needed to be done in my application to utilize the legacy endpoints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, your question is about SQS Queue endpoint not having the `us-east-1` appended at the beginning of the endpoint. It is not a legacy endpoint. In AWS, there are certain services that does not allow you to specify a region in the endpoint. Whatever that is being routed to this endpoint:  `https://queue.amazonaws.com/1234567890/queue-name.fifo`, will be automatically routed to `us-east-1` region in AWS.

This is clearly mentioned in the documentation in AWS related to Endpoints. ([Link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html))

> Some services, such as IAM, do not support regions; therefore, their
>   endpoints do not include a region. Some services, such as Amazon EC2,
>   let you specify an endpoint that does not include a specific region,
>   for example, https://ec2.amazonaws.com. In that case, AWS routes the
>   endpoint to us-east-1.